# Get Angular working with Waffle Spring boot + Spring Security and embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, waffle, negotiate, embedded-tomcat

I am using this example to find out more about waffle:

https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/tree/master/Source/JNA/waffle-demo/waffle-spring-boot-filter2

I am happy because everything works nice in this example. But adding a static HTML document to this spring boot project and starting this html page in my browser leads to an error:

```
2021-09-07 13:17:37.269 ERROR [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]         Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
    
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Authorization header: Negotiate
    at waffle.util.AuthorizationHeader.getSecurityPackage(AuthorizationHeader.java:94) ~[waffle-jna-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilter.java:104) ~[waffle-spring-security5-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:390) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

I guess that it depends to the configuration of my spring security filter. Does anybody has an example waffle, spring boot with embedded Tomcat which works with html or angular?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I customized my filter and it was working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).